# Trouble setting AVLayerVideoGravity with the AVKit for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avkit

I am very new to Swift and Xcode and I was trying to use a video as a transition from one scene to another. I have most of the code for this figured out but the size of the video does not match the size of the screen, meaning when the transition occurs the background changes size. I could fix this by changing the AVLayerVideoGravity but the commands in the documentation give me errors, and I haven't found a way to set them properly. I'm sure this is really simple I just can't find the syntax I need anywhere, especially in the newest versions of swift and Xcode so I thought I would ask. Here is the code I have.

```swift
import UIKit
import AVKit

class MainRoom: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func Backpack(_ sender: Any) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "OpenBackpack", ofType: "avi", inDirectory: "SegueAnimations")
        {
            let OpenBackpack = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            let animPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

            animPlayer.player = OpenBackpack
            animPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = true
            let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: OpenBackpack)

            //Set avlayervideogravity to resizeaspectfill

            present(animPlayer, animated: true, completion:
        {
                OpenBackpack.play()
        })
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If anyone knows how to call an action when a video ends I am also having trouble finding that for the latest swift versions, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I misunderstood the code in another post, this works well

animPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill